# UINavigationController: How to manage Cancel button and back button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Lets say I have two controller A & B... When I'll navigate from A to B then back button on B Controller will be A.

So my problem is... On a button click I have to change backButton to Cancel Button.. and on another back button it should appear backButton A in back button arrow style.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do the following,

*To **SHOW** the Cancel button:*

```
- (void)showCancelButton {

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(someMethod)];
    [self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:cancelButton];
    [cancelButton release];
}
```

*To **HIDE** the Cancel button:*

```
- (void)hideCancelButton {

    [self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nil];
}
```

Make sure *self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton*  is **NO**.